# Execute a bash script in remote server through URL

Tags: bash, execution

I have a bash script "Hello.sh" below in my remote server "A" which is running Apache.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Hello World" > Hello.txt
```

I want to execute this script in remote server "A" itself by calling it's Apache URL from server "B" like below.

Please note I have made the script available through URL by keeping it in Document root of Apache.

http://Server_A:PORT/Hello.sh

How can this be accomplished. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to run shell scripts directly from the browser, you should add this rule to your .htaccess file.

Options ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .sh

This tells the webserver to treat .sh files as CGI scripts.